# Connection in DaG - Using Connection() to connect to MsSQL Backend in Airflow

Tags: python, sql-server, airflow

We have our secrets stored in AWS Secrets manager. Hence I figured, let use Connection() to create connection to MsSQL and then use the Hook to execute SQL query.

```
c = Connection(
            conn_id="test_mssql_1",
            conn_type="mssql",
            description="connection description",
            host="**************",
            login="**************",
            password="*****************",
            schema="***********"
            #extra=json.dumps(dict(this_param="some val", that_param="other val*")),

        )

        
       
        mssql_hook = c.get_hook()
        
        
        data_records = mssql_hook.get_records("Select top 10 * from SomeTable")
```

However when executing this query, I get an error

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowNotFoundException: The conn_id `test_mssql_1` isn't defined
```

Any thoughts on what is incorrect or what should be the right approach ? This is the first foray inot COnnection() call. We dont want to use Connections from UI since our credentials come from Secrets Manager.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You never want to have secret information such as passwords in code for security reasons. When you call `get_hook()`, Airflow will look up the given connection id in Airflow's database. The error you're seeing says "I tried looking up connection `test_mssql_1` in the database but couldn't find it".

A better way to do this is to save the information as a "Connection" in the Airflow UI under Admin -> Connections, and then you can fetch the credentials at runtime by referencing the Connection id as:

```py
mssql_hook = MsSqlHook(mssql_conn_id="... your conn id ...")
data_records = mssql_hook.get_records("Select top 10 * from SomeTable")
```

Since you mention you're using AWS Secrets Manager, you might also want to look at "Secrets Backends" in Airflow, which enable you to automatically fetch credentials from other systems than Airflow's database:

- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/secrets-backend/index.html
- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/secrets-backends/aws-secrets-manager.html

Comment: The Secrets would eventually be replaced by AWS Secrets Manager calls. Ty for the callout.
Regarding saving Connection in Airflow UI, Is there a means to bypass this since we dont want to save credentials in Secrets Manager and in Airflow U. Trying to avoid storing in 2 places and would prefer AWS Secrets Manger if possible.

Comment: When a secrets backend is configured, Airflow will first check for the connection there, and second in the Airflow metastore as a fallback. There's no need to store secrets twice, Airflow will return a secret wherever it finds it first.